# How can I find the device file for a phone, so that I can mount it on my Linux?

Tags: mount, block-device, phone

I connect a phone to my Linux laptop using USB. I click File Transfer option in the pop-up window on the phone. In order to mount the phone on my Linux, I have to find the block device on my Linux. I suspect its device file is /dev/sdb1, but I can't find it:

```
$ sudo fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sda: 931.51 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk model: ST1000LM014-1EJ1
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 18E6169E-AE75-4F4D-82EE-32A4A1B85155

Device         Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1    1048576   69206015   68157440  32.5G Linux swap
/dev/sda2   69206016  195035135  125829120    60G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda3  195035136 1953523711 1758488576 838.5G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda4       2048    1048575    1046528   511M EFI System

Partition table entries are not in disk order.
```

and

```
$ sudo lsblk -l
NAME MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
sda    8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk 
sda1   8:1    0  32.5G  0 part [SWAP]
sda2   8:2    0    60G  0 part /nix/store
                               /
sda3   8:3    0 838.5G  0 part /home
sda4   8:4    0   511M  0 part /boot
sr0   11:0    1   3.3M  0 rom
```

`sudo lshw` shows the phone as:

```
    *-usb
         physical id: 14
         bus info: pci@0000:00:14.0
         version: 31
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=xhci_hcd latency=0
         resources: irq:129 memory:df410000-df41ffff
       *-usbhost:0
            product: xHCI Host Controller
            vendor: Linux 5.19.0 xhci-hcd
            physical id: 0
            bus info: usb@1
            logical name: usb1
            version: 5.19
            capabilities: usb-2.00
            configuration: driver=hub slots=16 speed=480Mbit/s
          *-usb:0
               description: Mass storage device
               product: FRD-AL10
               vendor: HUAWEI
               physical id: 1
               bus info: usb@1:1
               version: 2.99
               serial:  
               capabilities: usb-2.00 scsi
               configuration: driver=usb-storage maxpower=500mA speed=480Mbit/s
```

How can I find the device file for the phone, so that I can mount it on my Linux?

Thanks.

Comment: Likely it doesn't even expose any mass storage device at all but expect you to access via MTP.

Comment: @TomYan could you elaborate how to access via MTP?

Comment: There are quite a few MTP client implementations. I'm not sure which are available on your distro's package repo, but you can take [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Media_Transfer_Protocol) as a reference. (Also, you may need to choose another connection mode on the phone, with the item name being "media something", maybe. It seems that with the current mode your phone does expose an MSC device (without medium?), but the fact that you don't see any sdX for it probably means that it works only for the microSD, if any inserted.)

Answer (score 2):

As said by Tom Yan in the comments, you'll have to use MTP (*Media Transfer Protocol*).

There are various utilities you can use, here are two:

- `simple-mtpfs`
- `jmtpfs`

For example with `jmtpfs` (from the [official README](https://github.com/JasonFerrara/jmtpfs/blob/master/README)):

```
[jason@colossus ~]$ workspace/jmtpfs/src/jmtpfs -l
Device 0 (VID=04e8 and PID=6860) is a Samsung GT-P7310/P7510/N7000/I9100/Galaxy Tab 7.7/10.1/S2/Nexus/Note.
Available devices (busLocation, devNum, productId, vendorId, product, vendor):
2, 19, 0x6860, 0x04e8, GT-P7310/P7510/N7000/I9100/Galaxy Tab 7.7/10.1/S2/Nexus/Note, Samsung

You can choose which device to mount with the -device option.

[jason@colossus ~]$ workspace/jmtpfs/src/jmtpfs -device=2,19 ~/mtp
Device 0 (VID=04e8 and PID=6860) is a Samsung GT-P7310/P7510/N7000/I9100/Galaxy Tab 7.7/10.1/S2/Nexus/Note.
Android device detected, assigning default bug flags
[jason@colossus ~]$ ls ~/mtp
Internal Storage

Unmount with fusermount.

[jason@colossus ~]$ ls ~/mtp
Internal Storage
[jason@colossus ~]$ fusermount -u ~/mtp
[jason@colossus ~]$ ls ~/mtp
[jason@colossus ~]$
```

For more information, you can have a look at the *Archlinux* documentation:

- https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Media_Transfer_Protocol

For technical specifications:

- https://usb.org/document-library/media-transfer-protocol-v11-spec-and-mtp-v11-adopters-agreement

Answer (score 1):

Your `sudo lshw` indeed indicates the phone is presenting a USB Mass Storage interface for *something*:

```
      *-usb:0
           description: Mass storage device
           product: FRD-AL10
           vendor: HUAWEI
           physical id: 1
           bus info: usb@1:1
           version: 2.99
           serial:  
           capabilities: usb-2.00 scsi
           configuration: driver=usb-storage maxpower=500mA speed=480Mbit/s
```

(Google indicates the FRD-AL10 would be a China-only version of [Huawei Honor 8](https://www.gsmarena.com/honor_8-8195.php).)

But instead of `/dev/sdb1` you suspect, the device presented by the phone might be this one:

```
sr0   11:0    1   3.3M  0 rom
```

Note the size: just 3.3M. A regular empty CD/DVD drive looks like this:

```
sr0   11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

The phone might be simply presenting a built-in installation media image for a Windows driver and/or Windows Store installation link for phone backup/file transfer utility. With modern software, not much else will fit into 3.3M.

Once the utility is installed, it would then know how to communicate with the phone, most likely using the Media Transfer Protocol, as [ramius already said](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/755197/258991). Generally, modern phones seem to disfavor sharing their internal storage via USB Mass Storage protocol. Maybe MTP integrates better with security protections like the requirement to have the phone unlocked (and/or the connected computer previously identified and marked as trusted?) before transfers can happen?

Since you're using Linux, such automatically presented installation media image would be completely useless to you.

Comment: I wonder if it is technically possible to expose the "emulated SD card" as MSC device. Unlike when used on phone in which case it only need to mimick the "behavior", the phone would need to present a "virtual" drive that is (ex)FAT-formatted, if that's possible at all. The fuse/sdcardfs trick used for on-phone emulation probably can't apply. I guess that might be the reason they don't do MSC.

Comment: Also, there might be issues (e.g. uncoordinated write caching between the computer and the phone OS) in MSC-style sharing, compared to MTP. Sort of similar to how you can use NFS or CIFS to just access a network share on a regular filesystem from multiple computers simultaneously, but if you try to do the same using iSCSI or some other lower-level connectivity technology, you'll need a cluster-aware filesystem and/or coordination between the hosts, to prevent filesystem corruption by each host using default caching strategies incompatible with multiple access.